# Add same user in many site collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I need to add one user in more than 200 different site collection in sharepoint.Is there a program using spservices to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong then you want to assign a user from your active directory to site collection.

For this you can use powershell script and you can write all your site collection url into xml file and iterate this xml file using powershell script.

For more detail [Add a SharePoint or AD group/user to all sites in a site collection using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/add-sharepoint-or-ad-groupuser-to-all.html)

Please let me know your suggestion whether I am getting your point of view right or not.